# Set of vectors living in a manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, manifolds

Suppose I have a vector $x= [f_1(a) \; f_2(a) \; f_3(a)]^\top$ which is parametric on a scalar $a$. I can plot in a $3$D plane all the possible vectors $x$ by plugging different $a$s, and they form in general a curve in the $3$-dimensional space.

Since in general the set of vectors $x$ is not a vector space (because the $f_i$ are not linear), what is the mathematical term to describe such set of vectors? Somehow they reside in a one-dimensional manifold I think. Also, what kind of operations can I perform on such vectors and be sure that it still remains in the same manifold? Which branch of mathematics look at similar problem? Differential geometry?

Comment: A parametrized curve might be a $1$-dimensional manifold or it might not. A constant path would just give you a point. Certainly, the curve can cross itself or be badly non-smooth.

Comment: The branch of mathematics you want to look at is differential geometry of space curves. There are many books out there on differential geometry of curves and surfaces, any of which would give lots of answers to your questions. A very good that's available for free on the Internet was written by Ted Shifrin, who just commented on this post.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Vectors of the form $[1 \; x \; x^2 \;  x^3 ... x^n]$ for different $x$ would also form a one-dimensional manifold I guess ?

Comment: The first thing it is called is the "image of $f$" (where $f(t) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(t)\\f_2(t)\\f_3(t)\end{bmatrix}$ is the combined function into $\Bbb R^3$). If $f$ is not continuous (something you have not specified), then its image could be any subset of $\Bbb R^3$. If $f$ is continuous, then it is commonly called a "curve". But its image still could be some very unexpected sets, including all of $\Bbb R^3$ (look up "space-filling curves"). For it to be a 1-dimensional manifold, you need additional assumptions on $f$, such as having a continuous derivative, and not self-intersecting.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair, interesting concept. Related to my previous comment, would that family of vectors form a one dimensional manifold? Every function has continuous derivative....

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by that. In your post, $x$ is a vector. There no multiplication between vectors. What do $x^2, x^3, \dots, x^n$ mean? Or are you now using $x$ to represent a real number, and are referring to an $n$-dimensional vector for each value of $x$? If so, then yes, that particular curve in $\Bbb R^n$ is a $1$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Yes, I was misleading indeed. In my comment $x$ was just a scalar value, not related to the vector of the question. Pardon. How are the mapping among points of this 1-dimensional manifold called?  And is there a way to check the uniqueness of such mappings? This one the same vein as linear algebra, where you have for instance a matrix mapping a vector to another vector.